# how to select which columns to use in a regression?

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

Consider this simple example

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(dep_var = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 ind_1 = c(23,23,54,54,65),
                 ind_2 = c(1,4,5,3,2),
                 dont_touch_this = c(1,2,3,4,4))

> df
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  dep_var ind_1 ind_2 dont_touch_this
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
1       1    23     1               1
2       2    23     4               2
3       3    54     5               3
4       4    54     3               4
5       5    65     2               4
```

I would like to write a `function` that runs a `lm` linear regression where I can speficy the `dependent` variable I want to use as well as the `independent variables`.

The trick is that I would like to specify something like "use as indipendent variables all the variables that start with `some_string_pattern`"

Something like

```
myfunc <- function(df, dep_var, 'myregex' ){
  cols <- #select columns that start with myregex
  y <- lm(dep_var ~ cols)
}
```

I do not know how to proceed here. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
myfunc <- function(df, dep_var, cols){
  cols <-  grep(cols, colnames(df), value = T)
  Formula <- as.formula(paste(dep_var,"~",paste(cols, collapse = "+")))
  broom::tidy(lm(Formula, data = df))
  }

myfunc(df, "dep_var", "ind")
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept)  -0.181     1.15      -0.157  0.890 
2 ind_1         0.0762    0.0208     3.66   0.0673
3 ind_2        -0.0524    0.257     -0.204  0.857
```

Search the names using `grep`. Perhaps include `cols <- grep(dep_var, cols, value = T, invert = T)` to avoid that dependend variable is also found as independend variable. Then create the formula collapsing all variables on the right side together with `"+"`. Get nice output using `broom`'s `tidy` function.

in the `tidyverse`you can try this similar approach

```
foo <- function(df, dep_var, cols ){
  df %>% 
  select(a = quo_name(dep_var), starts_with(cols)) %>% 
  lm(a ~ ., data = .) %>% 
  broom::tidy()
}
foo(df, "dep_var", "ind")
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept)  -0.181     1.15      -0.157  0.890 
2 ind_1         0.0762    0.0208     3.66   0.0673
3 ind_2        -0.0524    0.257     -0.204  0.857
```

Answer (score 2):

With `select`, `matches` takes regex, so you can feed any regex straight from the function argument:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

myfunc <- function(df, dep_var, regex){
  dep_var_quo <- ensym(dep_var)
  df %>%
    select(!!dep_var_quo, matches(regex)) %>%
    lm(expr(!!dep_var_quo ~ .), data = .)
}

myfunc(df, dep_var, "^ind")
```

`ensym` turns the code that is being supplied when the function is called into a symbol. It can then be unquoted using `!!` in `select` and `expr`. This enables non-standard evaluation where you type `dep_var` as-is instead of a string `"dep_var"`. `enquo` is the same idea, but turns it into a quosure. `expr` is useful here because you can unquote quosures and it turns the entire code into an expression.

**Output:**

```
Call:
lm(formula = expr(!(!dep_var_quo) ~ .), data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        ind_1        ind_2  
   -0.18063      0.07621     -0.05241
```

Comment: nice! could you please explain what `ensym` and `quo_text` do here? why do I need these at all?

Comment: thanks! ive got to give it to Jimbou because he was first, but your solution is nice as well

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I actually found an even simpler approach using `expr`. See my update.

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Well, our solutions are different

Comment: arent the tidyverse solutions about the same?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Not really. Mine allows non-standard evaluation and regular expression for `select`. Even if they are. I post mine before he edited in his version.

Comment: next time buddy, its hard to take back a question. plus he has th most upvotes

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Oh I'm not saying to un-accept his. I'm just stating the fact that our answers are different, so they both deserve to be posted.